# What's the easiest way to map JSON array values to a dictionary using jq?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

How can I make a key value dictionary using jq?

If I do: `cat api_fm.json | jq -r "[ .[].name, .[].status ]"`
I receive:

```
[
  "plugin",
  "c_docker_2",
  "c_docker_5",
  "c_docker_4",
  "c_docker_3",
  "c_docker_1",
  "Started",
  "Started",
  "Started",
  "Started",
  "Started",
  "Started"
]
```

So, I would like to map the name with the status like this:

```
[
   "plugin: started"
...
]
```

Comment: Do you really want an array of strings, or do you want an actual object? `{"plugin": "Started", "c_docker_2": "Started", ...}`

Comment: In fact after this I would like to transform the output into a a dictionary like this:
declare -A prod= ( ['key']="value"
                   ['key']="value" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```bash
jq 'map("\(.name): \(.status)")'
```

Answer (score 0):

Working through the requirements in your comment. Given:

```bash
$ cat api_fm.json
[
  {"name":"plugin", "status":"Started"},
  {"name":"c_docker_2", "status":"Started"},
  {"name":"c_docker_5", "status":"Started"},
  {"name":"c_docker_4", "status":"Started"},
  {"name":"c_docker_3", "status":"Started"},
  {"name":"c_docker_1", "status":"Started"}
]
```

We can produce tab-separated name-status pairs like

```bash
$ jq -r '.[] | [.name, .status] | @tsv' api_fm.json
plugin  Started
c_docker_2  Started
c_docker_5  Started
c_docker_4  Started
c_docker_3  Started
c_docker_1  Started
```

Then, to create the bash associative array

```bash
declare -A prod

while IFS=$'\t' read -r name status; do
    prod["$name"]=$status
done < <(
    jq -r '.[] | [.name, .status] | @tsv' api_fm.json
)

declare -p prod
```

```bash
declare -A prod=([c_docker_2]="Started" [c_docker_3]="Started" [c_docker_1]="Started" [c_docker_4]="Started" [c_docker_5]="Started" [plugin]="Started" )
```

Comment: is a nice piece of code but the output of jq 'map("\(.name): \(.status)")' is actually in this form, "plugin: started", so I would need a new map rule to look like this [
  {"name":"plugin", "status":"Started"}, but yes I like your version. I don't find a good manual for the command  jq map...

Comment: Perhaps: https://exercism.org/tracks/jq/concepts/arrays